# Uncaught Error : Call to a member function isHtml() on string while using phpmailer library

Tags: php, email

I've been using the phpmailer library for a while now to send emails.

```
require '../class/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;  
$mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "";
$mail->Port       = port;
$mail->Host       = "my _server";
$mail->Username   = "user@domain.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";


$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress("$destination");
$mail->SetFrom("user@domain.com");
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$content = "content.....";
$mail->MsgHTML($content); 
if(!$mail->Send()) {
 // echo "Error while sending Email.";
  
} else {
  //echo "Email sent successfully";
}
```

Since yesterday I can no longer send them and I have this message

"PHP Fatal error : Uncaught Error : Call to a member function isHtml() on string"

Comment: Is there any other code between `$mail = new PHPMailer();`, and where the error occurs, that you aren't showing us?

Comment: yes a lot of code, but have only this error

Comment: OK, look for code that assigns a string to `$mail`.

Comment: i deplaced $mail = new PHPMailer(); near $mail->IsHTML(true); and it works now thank you very much